# Pausable BehaviorSubject?

Tags: java, scala, rx-java, observable, rx-scala

Is it possible to have a kind of `BehaviorSubject` with pause and resume switches? Something like `PausableBehaviorSubject.pause()` and `PausableBehaviorSubject.resume()`? How could that be done?

The idea is that, when paused, the subject would not forward the events received via `PausableBehaviorSubject.onNext()`, but instead only store the last one. Upon resuming (or upon subscription, if not paused), the `PausableBehaviorSubject` would forward the stored last event (if any) and forward the subsequent events to its subscriber(s).

Comment: something like this : `subject.filter(i -> !isPaused).replay(1).autoconnect()` ? (not tested..)

Comment: can't you just do `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` instead of `resume` and `pause`?

Comment: @SamuelGruetter the problem is that you'd be allowing the observer to control when it gets updates and when not. With a pausable observable, this could be encapsulated, and thus pausing/resuming would stay out of reach of the observer.

Comment: What you want sounds like applying backpressure to the observable. You can introduce a `Subject` that applies backpressure based on its state. Any upstream observables are responsible for buffering results until the backpressure is lifted.

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator that allows you to do this. It is called `pausableBuffered`. You can see an animation at: [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#pausableBuffered).

Your observer or subject would simply package the original observable, add a new Boolean observable, and flip the switch by providing the value of true or false to your new observable.